# Javascript onChange only when using mouse

Tags: javascript, onchange

I have a Javascript function that captures the onChange of a select dropdown. Is it possible to fire an event only when the user selects the item using the mouse form the dropdown, not when he scrolls up or down using the keyboard?

Comment: You could check for a click event. Although I'm not sure why you would want to do this, some disabled users need to use the keyboard or other form of input other than the mouse to do that.

Comment: won't onclick work?

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/ou8z1q47/ ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Have you tried this :

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>change demo</title>
  <style>
  div {
    color: red;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<select name="sweets" multiple="multiple">
  <option>Chocolate</option>
  <option selected="selected">Candy</option>
  <option>Taffy</option>
  <option selected="selected">Caramel</option>
  <option>Fudge</option>
  <option>Cookie</option>
</select>
<div></div>

<script>
$( "select" )
  .change(function () {
    var str = "";
    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
      str += $( this ).text() + " ";
    });
    $( "div" ).text( str );
  })
  .change();
</script>

</body>
</html>
  Trigger the handler
</div>
```

Comment: Please use raw javascript , not jquery . Question tag is about javascript and onchange.

Comment: try to use this :  $(document).on('change', '.entity', function(){
                var selectedCatId = $(this).val();

Answer (score 0):

check this solution, it ignores keyboard selection, only way to select it using a mouse

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function IgnoreAlpha(e)
{
if (!e)
{
    e = window.event ;
}
if (e.keyCode >= 65 && e.keyCode <= 90) // A to Z
{
    e.returnValue=false;
    e.cancel = true;
}
}
</script>

<body>
<p>
    <select id="MySelect" name="MySelect" onkeydown="IgnoreAlpha(event);"">
        <option selected="selected" value="" />
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
    </select>
</p>
</body>
```

This will definitely work for you

Answer (score 0):

Try this.This is working fine in IE but not in chrome. Don't know why?Tested using IE debugger tool(working fine)and also using VS2015 (IE,hitting break point onkeydown)working but not hitting breakpoint when run in chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function IgnoreArrow(e)
        {

        if (e.keyCode == 37 || e.keyCode == 38 ||  e.keyCode ==39 || e.keyCode ==40 )
        {
            return false;
        }
        }

        function myFun() {
            var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;

        }
</script>    
</head>
<body>    
        <p>
    <select id="mySelect" name="mySelect" onkeydown="return IgnoreArrow(event);" onchange="myFun()">
        <option selected="selected" value="" />
        <option value="Dream Theater">Dream Theater</option>
        <option value="Metallica">Metallica</option>
        <option value="Iron Maiden">Iron Maiden</option>
    </select>
</p>
<p id="demo"></p>


</body>
</html>
```